# regex pcre replace matched group by not matched group?

Tags: regex, replace, match, regex-group

someone can give me an example
for example for this string

```
wordride plain fire
```

replace the spaces by another letter

for example 
replace

the first  match space for the third letter before the space

for example i want to replace  character after word 
using this

```
   (?:\G(?!^)|word)\K.
```

replace character by word usign a "word" as group

```
      (?:\G(?!^)|(word))\K.
```

using $1$2

but not work

how could solve this problem

in this case

```
     wordride plain fire
```

for example when the algorithm  search  "r" replace this by the group "word"

obtain

```
     wordwordide plain fire
```

i want to find all letter after word character by character ( r i d e .......)
and replace by group word using subtitution $1 $2 etc

please help  me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace letter after `word` by captured group, you can use:

```
$s = 'wordride plain fire';

$r = preg_replace('/(?>(word)|\G(?<!^))\K\S/', '$1', $s, 1);

//=> wordwordide plain fire
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aI6gE1/2)

Comment: this work but i want to search all characters after "word" , this only search the first

Comment: You should clarify more because your expected output is `wordwordide plain fire` where only next char after `word` is being replaced

Comment: " wordride plain fire " i want find r or i or d or e , etc all after word

Comment: and replace by group  "word "

Comment: I want to know which is my error ,
and because I can not include word as a group use this command      ,                                    (?:\G(?!^)|(word))\K.                                                                                   the problem is that your command has a very different function       ,             only find the first character after word after that it stops the find,

Comment: sorry for the confusion

Comment: you may give me the same command but compatible with notepad ++?

Comment: I answered it assuming you have PCRE compatible regex. `Notepad++` also uses PCRE regex so it should work but I don't have access to `Notepad++`

Comment: work for php but not work in notepad++                                                        i dont know which is the problem